# Memory Leak in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate as our ORM and I am getting an Error of memory Leak.

I have observerd it in Task Manager that, whenever I tried to access the Home page from different web Browsers in the same PC, CPU usage is 2-3% but Memory usage get 80-90% which results in slowing of website and leads to system Hang.
And to run my webisite again I have to End the process from Task Manager. One more thing, when I access it from a Browser it use some memory but when i close it , It do no release all resources(that memory).

I have made the architecture of my webiste in this way  :-

1. I have made a class "ParentObject" in which i have created Repository object as a static member.
2. All Entities Which I have created have been Inherited from "ParentObject" Class.
3. I have made one more class BaseController which I have inherited from "Controller" class and in Base class I have used this code :-

   ```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      EdustructRepository Repository;  // My Repository Class where I have written logic for opening and closing Save and Update Session.I have mentioned my this logic below
       if (Session["Repository"] != null)
       {
           Repository = (EdustructRepository)Session["Repository"];
           if (!Repository.GetSession().Transaction.IsActive)
              Repository.GetSession().Clear();
       }
       else
       {
           Repository = new EdustructRepository(typeof(ActivityType), FluentNhibernateRepository.DataBaseTypes.MySql);
           Session["Repository"] = Repository;
       }
       if (ParentObject._repository == null)   
       {
           ParentObject._repository = new EdustructRepository();  // Here i have set the ParentObject's static variable "_repository" by this i have accessed repository in all my Entities .
       }
   }
   ```
4. And I have Inherited all my controller with BaseController Class. By this I have got the "_repository" object with every Action hit.

My session management Logic

```
public class EdustructRepository : NHibernetRepository
{

    public void Save<T>(T item, bool clearSession)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetProperty("Created_at").GetValue(item, null).ToString() == DateTime.MinValue.ToString())
        {
            typeof(T).GetProperty("Created_at").SetValue(item, MySqlDateTime.CurrentDateTime(), null);
        }
        typeof(T).GetProperty("Updated_at").SetValue(item, MySqlDateTime.CurrentDateTime(), null);
        base.CheckAndOpenSession();
        using (var transaction = base.GetSession().BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                base.GetSession().SaveOrUpdate(item);
                transaction.Commit();
                if (clearSession)
                {
                    Session.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                base.Evict(item);
                base.Clear();
                throw;
            }
        }
        //base.Save<T>(item, clearSession);
    }

    public void Save<T>(T item)
    {
        Save<T>(item, false);
    }
}

public class NHibernetRepository : IDisposable
{
    public static ISessionFactory _SessionFactory = null;

    protected ISession Session = null;

    private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DBConnectionString")))
          .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly((Assembly.Load("Edustruct.Social.DataModel"))).Conventions.Add<CascadeConvention>())
          .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass,"web"))
          .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    protected void CheckAndOpenSession()
    {
        if (_SessionFactory == null)
        {
            _SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
        }
        if (Session == null)
        {
            Session = _SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
        }
        if (!Session.IsOpen)
            Session = _SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        else if (!Session.IsConnected)
            Session.Reconnect();
    }    
 }
```

Note: We haven't closed Session in our Repository it is because I am using lazy Initialization also I have used it at Views so if I close session here I get an error showing "Session not found".

This is how I have made flow of my website.
Would you please review this code and let me know why I am getting this Error.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- you basicly hold one session per entity open forever. However ISession implements the unit of work pattern which is not meant for this.
- `CheckAndOpenSession()` is not thread safe but webserving is inherently threaded: each request typically gets its own thread.
- Whats the use

**Every business operation** should have its own session which is disposed of at the end of it. Business operation is typically a controller action or web method.

sample

```
// on appstart
GlobalSessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();


// in basecontroller befor action
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   DatabaseSession = GlobalSessionFactory.OpenSession();
}

// in basecontroller after action (pseudocode)
protected override void OnActionExecuted()
{
    DatabaseSession.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi Firo,

Thanx for your reply, I can not close the session here 

protected override void OnActionExecuted()

{

   DatabaseSession.Dispose();

 }

because I am using lazy initialization , and this will make use of session object on Views as I have coded on views also .. And the above event will be called before the rendering of view. So if I am closing it here it will give an Error  "Session not found".

Comment: IMO you should fix the "i use code in the view" because it will lead to hidden SELECT N+1 which kills performance in production. use eager fetching/fetch-paths in the action to mitigate the need for a open session in the view: much easier to reason, unittest, understand